# Jquery out put values issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having some issues with jquery.

I have a variable amount of libox's that have specific values in them.

I want to grab the data and on clikc out put it to a text area. but I'm having some problems with it.

here is my code:

```js
 $(".bottomtri.single_add_to_cart_button").click(function() {
   var slival = $("#mixers li .infora h3").text(),
     slivalmix = $("#mixers li .mix-value").text(),
     slivalimg = $("#mixers li .color-img").html(),
     slivaltotal = slivalimg + slival + slivalmix;
   $(".addon.addon-custom-textarea").val(slivaltotal);
 });
```

with this snippet might out put is just mashing everything together and its also adding up the numbers.

What I want it to do is go through each one and out put it like a list.

so it would have an out put like

```
h3 mix-value color-img
h3 mix-value color-img
h3 mix-value color-img
h3 mix-value color-img
```

Comment: could you provide your html code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop over the slide elements, and build up an array of strings. Then after the loop you can join the items in the array, and separate them with line breaks. You also need to add seperaters when you concatenate the values.

```
$(".bottomtri.single_add_to_cart_button").click(function() {

    var sliStrings = [];

    $("#mixers li").each(function () {
        var slival = $(".infora h3", this).text(),
            slivalmix = $(".mix-value", this).text(),
            slivalimg = $(".color-img", this).html(),
        sliStrings.push(slivalimg + " " + slival + " " + slivalmix);
    });

    $(".addon.addon-custom-textarea").val(sliStrings.join('\n'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You want spaces between the values, and you want numbers to be treated like text, then you have to put spaces in the output, this will also avoid numbers being added together

```
slivaltotal = slivalimg + " " + slival + " " + slivalmix
```